# class PDF extends FPDF not working

Tags: php, class, fpdf, extends

I am using FPDF to generate PDF invoices for osCommerce. My `pdfinvoice.php` file contains the following code to enhance the standard FPDF class:

```
class PDF extends FPDF {

}
```

For some reason unknown to me all functions defined within the PDF class are not working. To be able to successfully generate a PDF file I have go back to:

```
$pdf = new FPDF('P', 'pt', array(500,233));
```

instead of:

```
$pdf=new PDF( PDF_INV_PORTRAIT_LANDSCAPE,'mm', 'A4' );
```

In addition, any other reference to a function defined in the PDF class will stop the PDF file from being generated

NOTE: This behaviour only occurs when pdfinvoice.php is put into a specific subfolder. In my main folder all works fine!

For full details please refer to: http://forums.oscommerce.com/topic/271214-contribution-pdf-customer-invoice/page-34#entry1713911

Kind regards,

Dennis

Comment: What's the error you're getting? Also, does your PDF class call the FPDF constructor?

Comment: There are no visible errors. I've put `error_reporting(E_ALL); 
ini_set('display_errors',1);` in pdfinvoice.php, but that doesn't generate any output (error messages). For the contents of the class PDF, please check the provided link. The part you are looking for (constructor) is `function PDF($orientation='P',$unit='mm',$format='A4')
{
    //Call parent constructor
    $this->FPDF($orientation,$unit,$format);` I assume.